# Remove all words in file A from a list in a file B

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have two files: A and B.

Contents of A:

```
p218    first_departure_date    p219    2017-01-03  p220    sg40    Joe p221    expire_date 222 11-09-2024  p223    dob 224 00-00-0000  p225    gender  226 MR  p227    last_departure_date 228 2017-01-03
```

Contents from file B:

```
p219
p218
p220
p221
p227
p223
p225
p228
```

Expected results:

```
first_departure_date    2017-01-03  sg40    Joe expire_date 11-09-2024  dob 00-00-0000  gender  MR  last_departure_date 2017-01-03
```

Now, I would like to remove all the occurences of the lines in file A from file B.

I have tried following:

```
grep -vxFf fileB fileA > fileC
```

But it didn't do anything at all.

Comment: wrt `I would like to remove all the occurences of the lines in file A from file B` - you mean the opposite, right?

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk '
    NR==FNR { b[$1]; next }
    {
        c = 0
        for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
            if ( !($i in b) ) {
                printf "%s%s", (c++ ? OFS : ""), $i
            }
        }
        print ""
    }
' fileB fileA
first_departure_date 2017-01-03 sg40 Joe expire_date 222 11-09-2024 dob 224 00-00-0000 gender 226 MR last_departure_date 228 2017-01-03
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/[^[:alnum:]]/\\&/g;s/.*/s#&\\s*##g/' fileB | sed -f - fileA
```

This uses the fileB to create a sed script which removes any words in fileB followed by possible white space from fileA.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{print "s/"$0"//"}' fileB > out
sed -f out fileA -e 's/^[ ]//'
```

Sample output:

```
first_departure_date        2017-01-03      sg40    Joe     expire_date 222 11-09-2024      dob 224 00-00-0000      gender  226 MR      last_departure_date 228 2017-01-03
```